# substringToString producing leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsstring, substring

Ive been getting a memory leak at the line tempstr = [tempstr substringToIndex...
Ive tried every possible combination of allocation tempStr, 
NSString *tempStr = @"";
NSString *tempStr = [[NSString alloc] init]; (with a release at the end of the loop)
ive tried adjusting the scope of the NSString. NOTHING. Its producing 3 leaks
Any help on what i can try to fix it would be much appreciated.

```
while(x < [arr1 count]){
            //NSLog(@"%@", [arr1 objectAtIndex:x]);

            if([[arr1 objectAtIndex:x] rangeOfString:@".com"].location != NSNotFound)
            {

                //NSLog(@"%@", [arr1 objectAtIndex:x]);
                tempStr = [[arr1 objectAtIndex:x] substringFromIndex:[[arr1 objectAtIndex:x] rangeOfString:@"http://"].location];
                tempStr = [tempStr substringToIndex:tempStr.length - 1];
                [arr1 replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:tempStr];

                //NSLog(@"%@", [arr1 objectAtIndex:x]);

            }
..... more code....
x++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those `tempStr` instances should be going to the autorelease pool, thus if you are using the autorelease pool properly, they should be released properly, in due time.

Thus, you are either measuring the leak very early (the objects won't be released until long after the loop is finished), or you are working on a thread where the autorelease pool has not been setup properly.

Comment: ive been working under the assumption my autorelease pool is not set up properly. As far as i know, it should be done automatically for me... am i incorrect?

Comment: `NSString *tempStr = [[arr1 objectAtIndex:x] substringFromIndex:[[arr1 objectAtIndex:x] rangeOfString:@"http://"].location];
                tempStr = [tempStr substringToIndex:tempStr.length - 1];
                [arr1 replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:tempStr];
` also leaks